# Erro IMAP Certificate failure for imap.gmail.com

Tags: php-7, linux, apache, imap

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em que uso o Imap para se conectar ao gmail de um cliente, tudo funciona corretamente no local porém ao upar para o servidor e rodar o codigo recebo o seguinte erro `can't connect: Certificate failure for imap.gmail.com: self signed certificate: /OU=No SNI provided; please fix your client./CN=invalid2.invalid` em meu ambiente local a aplicação funciona perfeitamente sem um certificado, como posso resolver isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Depois de procurar a fundo descobri uma forma de resolver basta usar `imap/ssl/novalidate-cert` ficando `{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}` porém não é recomendavel uma vez que você ficará vulnerável a ataques [man-in-the-middle](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_man-in-the-middle)